# Kong returning 404 for Registered APIS

Tags: api, gateway, kong

I have installed Kong successfully and mapped a API by administration services provided by Kong as below:

`http://kong:8001/apis
payload:
{
"upstream_url": "http://test.suraj.com:9110/"
"strip_request_path": true
"request_path": "/services_test"
"preserve_host": false
"name": "services_test"
"request_host": "test.suraj.com"
}`

I am able to get this API when making get call to `http://kong:8001/apis`.

now I am trying to access my API endpoints using kong like:
`http://kong:8000/services_test/test.json`
its returning 404 " requested resource not found" .

what I am doing wrong? 
I am not able to access kong's log. can anyone tell me where kong stores log files?
Thanks for any help.
PS: all URLs are dummy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally, I got my answer.

What I doing wrong was setting `strip_request_path` property true.
By enabling the strip_request_path property on an API, the requests will be proxied without the request_path property being included in the upstream request.

In my case, actual API endpoint was:

`http://test.suraj.com:9110/services_test/test.json`

and Kong was redirecting request to :

`http://test.suraj.com:9110/test.json`

because `strip_request_path` property was true.

here is what documentation says about [How does Kong route a request to an API](https://getkong.org/docs/0.8.x/proxy/)

some more info from [google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/konglayer/ZEooisy6uE0/Rtf4fE11AwAJ)

Comment: This was really helpful

Answer (score 2):

use either `request_path` or `request_host`. don't use them both.

Answer (score 1):

How strip_request_path works is below:
assume `strip_request_path =true`
and `upstream_url"= "http://test.suraj.com:9110/"`
and `request_path= "/services_test"`

then :

- `test.suraj.com/services_test/test.json` will be mapped to `http://test.suraj.com:9110/test.json`
- `test.suraj.com/whatever/test.json` will return 404.

If request_path is the part of your actual endpoint you have to set strip_request_path property false. otherwise change  strip_request_path into something else eg `services123`. then your request url should look like below:

```
test.suraj.com/services123/services_test/test.json
```

then kong will forward this request on below end point:

```
http://test.suraj.com:9110/services_test/test.json
```